# Is flock automatically released on process exit?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, operating-system

In a bash script in Linux, I am using flock [the command flock, not the system call flock()] to implement file locking thereby guarding concurrent access against a shared resource [which is a file in tmpfs].

I have trap handlers to handle abnormal termination of my script:
`trap "{ rm -rf $LOCK ; rm -rf $TMPFS_FILE; exit 255; }" SIGINT SIGTERM`

where $LOCK is my lock file and $TMPFS_FILE is my shared resource.

My question is do I need to explicitly do a file unlock as well ? Or does Linux do it for me upon all program termination [both voluntary termination as well as forced] scenarios ?

Comment: Related question about flock() under Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918385/flock-question.

Comment: @CodeGnome i think this is about the command `flock`, not the system call `flock()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [`man 1 flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock):

> -u, --unlock
>
> ```
>           Drop  a  lock.   This  is  usually not required, since a lock is
>           automatically dropped when the file is closed.  However, it  may
>           be  required  in special cases, for example if the enclosed com‐
>           mand group may have forked a background process which should not
>           be holding the lock.
> ```