# Why is this file lock acquired with flock() not released after calling exec()?

Tags: php, locking

I have this minimal example for PHP 8.1:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
if(($fp = @fopen(__DIR__ . '/test.some', 'r+')) === false){
    $fp = fopen(__DIR__ . '/test.some', 'c+');
}
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
exec('eval `ssh-agent -s`', $output1, $resultCode1);
var_dump($output1, $resultCode1);
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is that when I run this script twice, then the second instance will block on the flock() function call, supposedly because the first one did not release the file lock.

When I exec() a different command instead of `` eval `ssh-agent -s` ``, such as `git --version`, then everything seems to work fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Is it a bug in PHP or my poor understanding of flock()?

Comment: Try adding       flock($fp, LOCK_UN) before fclose is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when a process exits all file locks are released automatically ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987606/is-flock-automatically-released-on-process-exit)). However, `ssh-agent` is forked as a background process, which causes it to inherit all file locks from the parent process.

This behavior can be confirmed by running `sudo fuser -v /tmp/test.some`, which shows us that `ssh-agent` inherited the lock.

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/tmp/test.some:      testuser    19834 F.... ssh-agent
                     testuser    19873 F.... php8.1
```

Adding `flock($fp, LOCK_UN)`, as suggested in the comments by Pran Joseph, indeed fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation. I had suspicion about something like that but wasn't sure if it's correct behaviour