# Allow only one instance of python script?

Tags: python, linux, locking, singleton, centos

I have a python script that I want to only allow to be running once on a machine. I want it to print something like "Error, already running" if it is already running, whether its running in the background or in a different ssh session. How would I do this? Here is my script.

```
import urllib, urllib2, sys
num = sys.argv[1]
print 'Calling'
phones = [
'http://phone1/index.htm',
'http://phone2/index.htm',
'https://phone3/index.htm',
'https://phone4/index.htm',
'https://phone5/index.htm'
]
data = urllib.urlencode({"NUMBER":num, "DIAL":"Dial", "active_line":1})
while 1: 
    for phone in phones:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(phone,data) # make call
            urllib2.urlopen(phone+"?dialeddel=0") # clear logs
        except: pass
```

P.S I am using CentOS 5 if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can implement a lock on the file.
2. Create a temp file at the start of the execution and check if that file is present before running the script.

Refer to this post for answer- [Check to see if python script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running)

Comment: If you're going to post just a link, you may want to quote from it a bit as well.

Comment: The thing about that is, the script is an infinite loop, so it would never get to the end of the script where the lock is removed.

Comment: I edited it after your comment.

Comment: This "answer" merely links to another one and copy-pastes question's code with two lines modified to include the name of the poster as "variable" (which is invalid anyway).

Answer (score 3):

You can install the [single](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/single/) package with `pip install single` that will use an advisory lock to ensure that only a single instance of a command will run without leaving stale lock files behind.

You can invoke it on your script like this:

```
single.py -c long-running-script arg1 arg2
```

Comment: PIP command not found. How would I do this on centos? There is no package single with yum

Comment: You may have to do `sudo easy_install pip` first. Then pip will download the single package automatically from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/single/

Comment: After installing pip, then doing pip install single, I get this  http://pastebin.com/6MTmHkMT

Comment: You're using a very old version of python (2.4) that does not have `walk_packages()`. You need to upgrade to at least 2.5, but preferably 2.7 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could lock an existing file using e.g. [flock](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock) at start of your script. Then, if the same script is run twice, the latest started would block. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918385/flock-question).

Comment: The thing about that is, the script is an infinite loop, so it would never get to the end of the script where the lock is removed.

Comment: You could add a handler for `SIGTERM` or `SIGQUIT` which clears a fleg used as a looping condition.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to do this and what it means? As I am new to python

Comment: You can use the [single wrapper script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12240440/462302) to avoid leaving stale lock files around.

Comment: @CJSculti In Linux(and unix) in general there is a thing called a signal.  When you run kill program it sends a SIGTERM(signal terminate ), when you press Ctrl-C to stop a program running in a shell it sends SIGINT(signal interrupt).  Your program can register a callback with the OS to handle those signals.  Then when you send a signal to your program it could clean up nicely and exit.